# Wrapper custom class for scikit-learn's Iterative Imputer for use with cross_val_score()

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, missing-data, imputation

Scikit-learn's Iterative Imputer can impute missing values in a *round-robin* fashion. To evaluate its performance against other conventional regressors, it is possible to build a simple pipeline and get scoring metrics from cross_val_score. The issue is that Iterative Imputer does not have a 'predict' method as per error:

```
AttributeError: 'IterativeImputer' object has no attribute 'predict'
```

See a minimum example of what is trying to be achieved:

```
# import libraries
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.experimental import enable_iterative_imputer
from sklearn.impute import IterativeImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

# define scaler, model and pipeline
scaler = StandardScaler() # use any scaler
imputer = IterativeImputer() # with any estimator, default = BayesianRidge()
pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[('s', scaler), ('i', imputer)])

train, test = df.values, df['A'].values 
scores = cross_val_score(pipeline, train, test, cv=10, scoring='r2')
print(scores)
```

What possible solutions exist? If a custom wrapper is needed, how should it be written to include the 'predict' method?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: you have to add `model` as last element in `Pipeline`. And `model` will have `predict`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cross_val_score` needs `pipeline` with `model` at the end (which has `predict`)

```
scaler  = StandardScaler()
imputer = IterativeImputer()
model   = BayesianRidge()  # any model

pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[('s', scaler), ('i', imputer), ('m', model)])
```

`cross_val_score` without `model` make no sense.

---

I see also other problem - with values `train`, `test` which you use in `cross_val_score`.

It should be `X`, `y` instead of `train`, `test` but it is only names so it is not so importalt but important is what you assing to variables.

Problem is that `X` should be without `y` but you use `train = df.values` so you create `X` with `y`

```
df_train = pd.DataFrame({
                'X': range(20), 
                'y': range(20),
           })

X_train = df_train[ ['X'] ]  # it needs inner `[]` to create DataFrame, not Series
y_train = df_train[  'y'  ]  # it has to be single column (Series)

scores = cross_val_score(pipeline, X_train, y_train, cv=10, scoring='r2')
```

(BTW: you don't have to use `.values`)

The same with more columns

```
df_train = pd.DataFrame({
                'A': range(20), 
                'B': range(20), 
                'y': range(20),
           })

X_train = df_train[ ['A', 'B'] ]
y_train = df_train[ 'y' ]
```

---

Minimal working code but with fake data (which are useless)

```
# import libraries
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.experimental import enable_iterative_imputer
from sklearn.impute import IterativeImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import BayesianRidge

df_train = pd.DataFrame({
                'A': range(100),  # fake data
                'B': range(100),  # fake data
                'y': range(100),  # fake data
           })

df_test = pd.DataFrame({
                'A': range(20),  # fake data
                'B': range(20),  # fake data
                'y': range(20),  # fake data
           })

# define scaler, model and pipeline
scaler  = StandardScaler()
imputer = IterativeImputer()
model   = BayesianRidge()

pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[('s', scaler), ('i', imputer), ('m', model)])

X_train = df_train[ ['A', 'B'] ]  # it needs inner `[]` to create DataFrame, not Series
y_train = df_train[ 'y' ]         # it has to be single column (Series)

scores = cross_val_score(pipeline, X_train, y_train, cv=10, scoring='r2')
print(scores)

X_test = df_test[['A', 'B']]
y_test = df_test['y']

scores = cross_val_score(pipeline, X_test, y_test, cv=10, scoring='r2')
print(scores)
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response and posting advice! If IterativeImputer() method was to be used as a regressor method itself to predict missing values, then how would that be possible? For example, given columns A, B and C and the purpose was to use IterativeImputer() to predict (and impute) values for column C using columns A, B (with a defined regression estimator).

Comment: `IterativeImputer` is only to fill missing values - not to predict values. MAybe it use regresion to fill values but it wasn't create to work as real model for prediction. It was created only to fill missing values before they will be used with real model. It is used only for preprocessing data.